# LWC: remove tags from HTML (view)

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, view, remove

JS

```
    openModal(event){

        let modal = this.template.querySelector('[data-id="modalUI"]');
        modal.classList.remove('hide');

        const searchKey = event.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-id');  
        
        if ( searchKey ) {  

            getRelatedMedia( { productId: searchKey } )
            .then(result => {  
                if(result.length > 0){
                    this.mediaAll = result;
                    this.mediaStatus = false;
                } else {
                    this.mediaAll = undefined;
                    this.mediaStatus = 'Not enough media to show';
                }
            })  
            .catch(error => {  
                this.mediaAll = undefined;
                this.mediaStatus = 'Error fetching data';
                this.MediaError = error;
            });  
            
        } else  {
            this.mediaStatus = 'There is no media to be showed';
            this.mediaAll = undefined;          
        }
    }
```

HTML

```
    <div class="modalUI hide" data-id="modalUI">
        <div class="helperUI">
            <div class="contentUI">
                <button class="closeButtonUI" onclick={closeModals}>x</button>

                <template if:true={mediaAll}>
                    <div class="sliderUI">
                        <div class="wrapper">
                            <div class="slides">
                                <template for:each={mediaAll} for:item="m">
                                    <div class="slide" key={m.Id}>
                                        <!-- <a href="#"> -->
                                            <img src={m.osf_URI__c} alt={m.osf_MediaDescription__c} />
                                            <small>{m.osf_MediaDescription__c}</small>
                                        <!-- </a> -->
                                    </div>
                                </template>
                                <template if:true={mediaStatus}>
                                    <div class="slide">
                                        <p>{mediaStatus}</p>
                                    </div>                                    
                                </template>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </template>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

the `this.mediaAll = result;` is an object with an array and values inside of it.
one of these values is a description, which comes with tags wrapping it: `<p>description</p>`
how can I remove the tags? is it possible using the HTML only?

Answer (score 1):

Could define a function like this to strip it without using any regex:

```
strip(html) {
   var temp = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument("New").body;
   temp.innerHTML = html;
   return temp.textContent || temp.innerText || "";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a regex to easily strip all HTML tags.

```
const originalString = '<p>description</p>';

const strippedString = originalString.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/gi, "");

console.log(strippedString); //outputs 'description'
```